# How To Delete Previously Drawn Line With a Mouse Click in Python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, tkinter

I would like to delete a line drawn on canvas using Tkinter/Python with a mouse click.

This code draws the line as object, and then immediately deletes it:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
from Tkinter import *

master = Tk()
w = Canvas(master, width=200, height=200)
w.pack()
i=w.create_line(0, 0, 100, 100)
w.delete(i)

mainloop()
```

What would the code be to do the line deletion on mouse click (left or right button doesn't matter) ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from Tkinter import *
import math

master = Tk()
w = Canvas(master, width=200, height=200)
w.pack()
x1=0
y1=0
x2=100
y2=100
delta=10
i=w.create_line(x1, y1, x2, y2)

def click(event):
# event.x is the x coordinate and event.y is the y coordinate of the mouse
    D = math.fabs((event.y-event.x))/math.sqrt(2)    
    if D < delta and x1 - delta < event.x < x2 + delta:
            w.delete(i)    
w.bind("<Button-1>", click)

mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1):

This will do it:

```
from Tkinter import *

master = Tk()
w = Canvas(master, width=200, height=200)
w.pack()
i=w.create_line(0, 0, 100, 100)

# Bind the mouse click to the delete command
w.bind("<Button-1>", lambda e: w.delete(i))

mainloop()
```

**Edit in response to comment**:

Yes, the above solution will register a mouse click anywhere in the window.  If you want it to only delete the line if the click is close to it, you will need something more complex.  Namely, something like this:

```
from Tkinter import *

master = Tk()
w = Canvas(master, width=200, height=200)
w.pack()
i=w.create_line(0, 0, 100, 100)

def click(event):
    # event.x is the x coordinate and event.y is the y coordinate of the mouse
    if 80 < event.x < 120 and 80 < event.y < 120:
        w.delete(i)

w.bind("<Button-1>", click)

mainloop()
```

This script will delete the line only if the `x` and `y` coordinates of the mouse click are withing 20 points of the line.

Note that I cannot perfectly set this.  You will have to tweak it to your needs.

Comment: I noticed that this will also delete the line when mouse pointer is quite far away from the line (an inch or so). Is there a way to delete the line when pointer is closer to it ?

Comment: @Platypus - You can get the x and y coordinates of the mouse click and then delete the line only if they are within a certain distance of the line.  See my edit.

Comment: Unfortunately, this only works in a square area toward the end of the line. The 20 point area does not follow all the way along the line. I think there has to be a line equation programmed into it somehow.

Comment: One needs to take care of the points along the line as well as the endpoints. There is a little bit of geometry involved. Finally i have the code working for the given line segment. If only the whole line is considered instead of a segment, the check for endpoints can be left out.